# SQL in a prepared statement with inner join SQL statement

Tags: php, sql, inner-join

my query is working but I don't know how to put it in a prepared statement
This is my query(working)

```
SELECT P.first_name, P.middle_name, P.last_name, P.lrn, P.section
FROM students P INNER JOIN student_load C ON P.lrn = C.lrn
WHERE subject_code = 12332654
```

This is my prepared statement(I'm new to the prepared statement so I don't know much)

```
function get_total_all_records()
{
     include('../config.php');

    //IM NOT SURE IF THE PROBLEM IS HERE($statement)
    $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT P.first_name, P.middle_name, 
                                        P.last_name, P.lrn, P.section
                                        FROM students P 
                                            INNER JOIN student_load C ON P.lrn = C.lrn");
     $statement->execute();
     $result = $statement->fetchAll();
     return $statement->rowCount();
}

$query = '';
$output = array();

// OR IF THE PROBLE IS HERE($query)
$query = "SELECT P.first_name, P.middle_name, P.last_name, P.lrn, P.section
          FROM students P INNER JOIN student_load C ON P.lrn = C.lrn
          WHERE subject_code = 12332654";
if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"])){
    $query .= 'AND ( lrn LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"
               OR teacher LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"
               OR sem LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" )';
}
```

Comment: Use placeholders in place of every value. Then bind the values. e.g. instead of `LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%"` use `LIKE ?` then put `'%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%'` into an array and pass that array into the `execute` function.

Answer (score 1):

One of the points of preparing a query is that you can use parameters for the parts you want to replace with data. This helps to protect you from [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) which concatenating variables into the string does not.

As your first query has no need of parameters it could quite happily be run using a simple `->query()` but the second would be best run using a prepare and execute

```
$params = [':subjcode'=>$subject_code];

$query = "SELECT P.first_name, P.middle_name, P.last_name, P.lrn, P.section
          FROM students P INNER JOIN student_load C ON P.lrn = C.lrn
          WHERE subject_code = :subjcode ";

if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"])){

    $query .= 'AND ( lrn LIKE :s1
               OR teacher LIKE :s2
               OR sem LIKE :s3 )';

    $params = array_merge($params, 
                            [':s1'=> '%' . $_POST["search"]["value"] . '%'],
                            [':s2'=> '%' . $_POST["search"]["value"] . '%'],
                            [':s3'=> '%' . $_POST["search"]["value"] . '%']
                        );

}

$stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

> Note I also added a space after `:subjcode ";` which was missing in your original query

Comment: The query is working but when I use it to the rest of the code it doesn't show any result.

Comment: Hi, thats a New Question. Please ask a new question. By the way that new code is full of simple syntax errors. I will rollback your question to its original state.